# QPixmap of a QGraphicsTextItem

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

How do you convert/paint a QGraphicsTextItem into a QPixmap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add it to a `QGraphicsScene` (if it's not already inside one) and then `render()` the scene to a `QPixmap` using a `QPainter`

```
QPixmap pix(100, 100);
QPainter paint(&pix);
scene.render(&paint);
```

Or, you can save yourself the trouble and just use `QPainter::drawText()` after changing the current font of the painter. it should provide the same capabilities.

Maybe something like this-

```
QPixmap pix(100, 100);
QPainter paint(&pix);
paint.drawText(0, 0, "Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

The QGraphicsTextItem::document() function is the back door you're looking for:

```
// pItem is a QGraphicsTextItem *
QPixmap srcPixmap(pItem->boundingRect().size().toSize());

QPainter tmpPainter(&srcPixmap);
pItem->document()->drawContents(&tmpPainter);
tmpPainter.end()
```